# Check if same values appear in swatch gallery/document Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am at the end of finishing a Vue gradient swatch generator, and wanting to do a check if the same swatch name or exact hex values appear in the grid or document. Values are collected via an $emit, "value1, value2, name) etc but once the swatch is inserted that wont be the same anymore, they are then just a h5 and p tag in each individual swatch. Also, the 2 hexs gradient gets converted to rgb

So wanting to do a conditional check if a swatch exists with either the same name or the exact combination of the same two hex values before insertion of subsequent swatches in to the grid. looks like it might be some kind of regex but cant figure it out. or maybe could do a querySelector to get all the h5 and p tags values in the swatch row grid and check against that with "contains" or whatever. Below is image of the structure of each finished swatch in html they are all the same

[image: Swatch HTML]

Tips welcome

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you store all your swatch values as an array in your data object?

Comment: Ah yes, create a swatches data object and just store the gradient and name values? data() {
    return {
      value1: null,
      value2: null,
      value3: null,
      swatches: []
    }   how to get them in there on each swatch creation, as gradient and name? Have got the gradient as  let gradient = `linear-gradient(to right, ${this.value1}, ${this.value2})`;  and name as  let name = (`${this.value3}`);

Comment: Use Vuex? Ive already made the methods though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all the information you need within a list of objects:

```
data: () => ({
    items : [
      {
        id : 1,
        color1 : 'blue',
        color2 : '#fff',
        name: 'swatchName1'
      },
      {
        id : 2,
        color1 : 'red',
        color2 : '#fff',
        name: 'swatchName2'
      }
    ]
  }),
```

When you need to add a swatch, just push a new object to the array.

One way to validate whether a swatch already exists is to create a method which combines the relevant info into a string: 
`gradientString (x) { return x.color1 + x.color2 }`

Then use another method to compare your new swatch to an array of existing existing:

```
isUnique(swatch) { 
 return !this.items.map(gradientString).includes(gradientString(swatch)) 
}
```

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ellisdod/23puw5t9/

Comment: Ok great, I dont need to use Vuex then, a bit overkill for this.

Comment: I created 4 default ones, what is best way to put them in by default to app? items : [
      {
        id : 1,
        value1 : 'blue',
        value2 : '#fff',
        name: 'Pacific Silk'
      },
      {
        id : 2,
        value1 : 'red',
        value2 : '#fff',
        name: 'Artistic Demolition'
      },
       {
        id : 3,
        value1 : 'red',
        value2 : '#fff',
        name: 'Masochistic Sunrise'
       },
       {
        id : 4,
        value1 : 'red',
        value2 : '#fff',
        name: 'Futuristic Bedlam'
       }
    ]

Comment: The easiest way is to include them in your data object. If there are many and you want cleaner code you could load them from a json file or if you want more control, an external database but for this the data object is most likely the way to go.

Comment: So example can be used in my boostrap row col-md-3s with v-for etc?

Comment: Ive got it in Vue app now, but it not adding the swatch, its showing the default two swatchs, doesnt seem to be collecting the values properly. <div class="row gallery">
 <div v-for="item in items" class="col-md-3 swatch" :key="item.id" :style="{backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient('+item.color1 +','+item.color2 +')'}">
</div>
</div>
 
Its exactly the same methods and inputs/button, also no v-model?

Comment: It is logging the color values, but not pushing the object to array.?  newSwatch () {
      this.$emit('input', {
      color1: +this.value1,
      color2: +this.value2,
      });
      return {
         id : this.items.length + 1,
         color1 : this.value1,
         color2 : this.value2
      }
    },
 
    addSwatch () {
       const swatch = this.newSwatch()
       if (this.isUnique(swatch)) {
       this.items.push(swatch);
       }
       console.log(swatch.color1);
       console.log(swatch.color2);
    }
  }

Comment: How to add the  other info name and swath vales in div below this using v-if, cant be in the same div, as it needs to be white background?

Comment: Hi, did you get it working? Move the v-for and key to a parent div and add the details to a sibling. I've updated the fiddle with example.

Comment: Its not pushing the array, I have got it set up, it is collecting and logging the color values, but not pushing, Ive added a namestring but thats not used yet as for some reason the form disappeared https://github.com/xhostcom/vue-gradient-swatch-builder.git

Comment: Cant get it to push the items for some reason, it is collecting the values, and logging them, but not pushing to array.

Comment: Got it to this http://uttermost-team.surge.sh its not pushing items, but is logging the values. Code is at https://github.com/xhostcom/vue-gradient-swatch-generator.git

Comment: Just push a new item to the items array, as in the jsfiddle example. Vue will generate the html based on the template, you don't need to create elements from within your method.

Comment: Its just not pushing anything though, the publish button runs the adSwatch method, nothing happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211659/discussion-between-ellisdod-and-paul-anthony-mcgowan).